# are bpy.context.object and bpy.context.active_object STILL the same?

Tags: python, scripting

So far I haven't found a clear distinction between `bpy.context.object` and `bpy.context.active_object`, are they currently interchangeable? If so, might they be different in the future?

**edit:** Blender continues to evolve - **are these still interchangeable**? Are they identical? Is there any plan or thought given to give them separate meanings being thought about for the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do appear to be interchangeable at the moment. I have seen no evidence that developers plan to change this. For sake of consistency I prefer to use `.active_object` for everything that requires the active object.

Comment: Thanks @zeffii. That's what I've been doing, but always felt like at any moment something would fall apart because I used the wrong one.

Comment: My rule of thumb is, if I have to use `.active_object` maybe there's a better way, usually writing my own versions of the things `bpy.ops` provides. For many things doing the low level non bpy.ops approach takes less code, but that's something you'll only appreciate after switching over :)