# Python: Traceback (most recent call last): line 131, in execute in button3 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, interface, add-on

I was making a Blender add-on that can create a predefined light-setup and generate HDRIs. For this it changes some settings of the camera in the scene.

The script creates two sections named *Illumin8r Quick Lights* and *Illumin8r HDRI Maker* in the *Scene Properties* tab with each two buttons. The HDRI buttons require the camera to be selected in order to change its settings.

I run into this error when I click the buttons <kbd>Turn scene into HDIR</kbd> and <kbd>Turn settings back to normal</kbd> in the *Illumin8r HDRI Maker* section (*LayoutDemoPanel2* class in the script):

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\....\w3.blend\Text", line 147, in execute
  File "C:\Users\....\w3.blend\Text", line 131, in button3
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data
```

The error seems to be related with the following lines

```
def button3(context):
    // ...
    bpy.context.object.data.type = 'PANO'
    bpy.context.object.data.cycles.panorama_type = 'EQUIRECTANGULAR'
```

and

```
def button4(context):
    bpy.context.object.data.type = 'PERSP'
    bpy.context.object.data.cycles.panorama_type = 'FISHEYE_EQUISOLID'
```

The script looks like this:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Illumin8r",
    "author": "BinaryOdysseus",
}

import bpy
target_obj = bpy.context.scene.objects[0]

collection = bpy.context.collection

def create_point_light1(name):
    
    light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name=name, type='POINT')
    light_data.color = (1,1,1)
    light_data.energy = 100
    light_data.shadow_soft_size = 1.75

    light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name=name, object_data=light_data)
    light_object.location = (1.35, -2.5, 2.56)
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)

def create_point_light2(name):
    
    light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name=name, type='POINT')
    light_data.color = (1,1,1)
    light_data.energy = 250
    light_data.shadow_soft_size = 1.75

    light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name=name, object_data=light_data)
    light_object.location = (-1.175, -5.5, 4.64)
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)
    
def create_point_light3(name):
    
    light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name=name, type='POINT')
    light_data.color = (1,1,1)
    light_data.energy = 500
    light_data.shadow_soft_size = 2.15

    light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name=name, object_data=light_data)
    light_object.location = (-6.7, -0.1, 2.2)
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)
    
def create_point_light4(name):
    
    light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name=name, type='POINT')
    light_data.color = (1, 0.612277, 0.441099)
    light_data.energy = 1000
    light_data.shadow_soft_size = 3.17
    
    light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name=name, object_data=light_data)
    light_object.location = (0, -0.6, 3.2)
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)
    
def create_spot_light(name):
    
    light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name=name, type='SPOT')
    light_data.color = (1, 0.868938, 0.686679)
    light_data.energy = 10000
    light_data.spot_size = 180


    light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name=name, object_data=light_data)
    light_object.location = (0, 0, 14)
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)
    

    
def create_sun_light(name):
    
    light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name=name, type='SUN')
    light_data.color = (1, 0.984, 0.675)

    light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name=name, object_data=light_data)
    light_object.location = (0, 0, 14)
    light_constraint = light_object.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO')
    light_constraint.target = target_obj
    light_constraint.track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
    light_constraint.up_axis = 'UP_Y'
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)



def button1(context):
    create_point_light1("Point")
    create_point_light2("Point")
    create_point_light3("Point")
    create_point_light4("Point")
    create_spot_light("Spot")
    create_sun_light("Sun")


class Add_Lights(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "illumin8r.add_lights"
    bl_label = "Add quick lights"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        button1(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
def button2(context):
    bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type = 'LIGHT')
    bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)

class Remove_Lights(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "illumin8r.remove_lights"
    bl_label = "Remove all lights"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        button2(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
def button3(context):
    bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
    bpy.context.object.data.type = 'PANO'
    bpy.context.object.data.cycles.panorama_type = 'EQUIRECTANGULAR'
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 200
    bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'HDR'

    
class Make_Scene_HDRI(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "illumin8r.make_scene_hrdi"
    bl_label = "Turn scene into HDRI"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        button3(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
def button4(context):
    bpy.context.object.data.type = 'PERSP'
    bpy.context.object.data.cycles.panorama_type = 'FISHEYE_EQUISOLID'
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100
    bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'

class Make_Scene_Normal(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "illumin8r.make_scene_normal"
    bl_label = "Turn settings back to normal"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        button4(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
        
    
def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text=SimpleOperator.bl_label)


class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Illumin8r Quick Lights"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene

        # Big buttons
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 1.25
        row.operator("illumin8r.add_lights")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 1.25
        row.operator("illumin8r.remove_lights")

class LayoutDemoPanel2(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Illumin8r HDRI Maker"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout_2"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene

        # Big buttons
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 1.25
        row.operator("illumin8r.make_scene_hrdi")

        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 1.25
        row.operator("illumin8r.make_scene_normal")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Make_Scene_HDRI)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Make_Scene_Normal)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Remove_Lights)  
    bpy.utils.register_class(Add_Lights)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel2)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Make_Scene_HDRI)  
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Make_Scene_Normal)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Remove_Lights)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Add_Lights)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! You need to add more details to your question. **1)** where are the buttons that cause the error? (**A:** *Scene Properties tab > Illumin8r HDRI Maker*) **2)** what's the name of the button? (**A:** *button Turn scene into HDRI*) **3)** Must an object be selected? Also, the error occurs in **line 131** not 147: *bpy.context.object.data.type = 'PANO'*. The object is the active object. **4)** What kind of object should that be? Mesh objects like the default cube have not data.type. This is what the error tells you. **5)** What means 'PANO'? **6)** What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Ok, you have to select the *Camera* object to make your script work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following function that is executed when the button "Turn scene into HDRI" is pressed:

```
    def button3(context):
        bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
        bpy.context.object.data.type = 'PANO'
        bpy.context.object.data.cycles.panorama_type = 'EQUIRECTANGULAR'
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 200
        bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'HDR'
```

1. you use `bpy.context` and not the given `context` object
2. the error happens because in your case (or better *context*) `context.active_object` is the camera and `context.object` is `None`. They are *not* the same. See the question "https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/204074/107598" for another side case.

Fixed version:

```
    def button3(context):
        context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
        context.active_object.data.type = 'PANO'
        context.active_object.data.cycles.panorama_type = 'EQUIRECTANGULAR'
        context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 200
        context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'HDR'
```

Do the same for `def button4(context):`.

you could also create a new object like this:

def button3(context):

```
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 200
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'HDR'

camera_data = bpy.data.cameras.new(name="hi")


camera_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="HDRI Camera", object_data=camera_data)
camera_object.location = (0, 0, 4)
camera_object.data.type = 'PANO'
camera_object.data.cycles.panorama_type = 'EQUIRECTANGULAR'



bpy.context.collection.objects.link(camera_object)
```